# Proteus 8.15 PCB trace not connecting

Tags: pcb-design, proteus

Proteus Ares. When I am connecting (say) a pad to a via quite often I put in a trace and the ratsnest does not disappear. It seems I have to very precisely position the trace. Unfortunately, there is no indication when I am routing as to whether a trace has really connected or not.

Am I missing something or is this just a PITA "feature"?

Comment: I think this is a common "feature" of PCB programs.  Altium and KiCad also require tracks to hit the "hot spot" of a pad to show a connection.

Comment: @PeterBennett I would not think it would take a genius programmer to flag when a connection was made, or not made. There's just nothing until all the routing fails to get rid of the ratsnest.

Comment: Try looking for a setting named "snap to grid" or anything with "snap".